# Running unit test using Xunit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, uwp, xunit

I have added a unit testing class and added the below references to my main class library in the UWP project.

[image: references]

When I add a new class library and add my test classes there the test methods on the class library execute but the test methods on the main project throw the below exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The following test container was not found: 'F:\test\WinApp\bin\x64\Debug\WinApp.exe'. This can be resolved by one or more of the following steps:
1. The test container does not exist on disk and the corresponding project might need to be built successfully.
2. For .NET Core based test projects, please ensure that a nuget package reference to "Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK" exists and that it uses the latest stable version.
3. For .NET based test projects, the project might be marked as a non-test project through an msbuild property, "IsTestProject". Please consider clearing it or set "<IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>" in a "<PropertyGroup>" in the test project.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.TestContainer.TestContainerProvider.<GetTestContainerAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
```

I tried the above approaches but no use.

I want to write my test classes inside my main class library which is executable any suggestions.I am trying this as I cannot add references to the main class library from the test project and run it.Below error throws if I try to do so.

[image]
My test project is a Unit Test App(Universal Windows)

[image]

I am not running in a build server

Comment: "*I want to write my test classes inside my main class library which is executable any suggestions*" - yeah sure, my suggestion is don't do that, and write tests in separate projects like 99.9879% of coders do.

Comment: I cannot add reference of my main project to  the test project  @TheGeneral

Comment: @PMBG - If you're not able to add references of main project, then this could be due to mismatch in .NET versions. Make sure your Unit Test project and main project are running on same .NET version. If not, change your target framework in settings to ensure same version.

Comment: @YashGupta I have added a screenshot of the  issue I get when I try to run my test project after I add a reference to the main project

Comment: This throws when I deleted .rd.xml and run. `The text associated with this error code could not be found. [0x80040905]
DEP7100: Failed to activate app 'b0f80232-6cf1-4666-980e-d6ab60bfcbda_zhcz0pjxj1ere!vstest.executionengine.universal.App' with parameters '--port 59799 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:059799 --role client --parentprocessid 26336 --telemetryoptedin true'. COMException - The text associated with this error code could not be found.` @YashGupta

Comment: @YashGupta I am not running this ina build server

Comment: Try building your project using .NET Native tool chain (Right click and open Project properties, go to Build tab, and select the checkbox that says "Compile with .NET Native tool chain"

Comment: Test project or main UWP project @YashGupta

Comment: The main UWP project

Comment: @YashGupta tried that no use